# IRC client application, how to use select() in python

Tags: python, multithreading, select

Hi am working on network application that reads from standard input and sends messages to server both in infinite loops. For every loop I have thread, that calls function with what should be done. I need to be able to catch SIGINT and close both threads properly. My program is stucked on both reading functions. I think I should use select() function, but I dont know how.

```
def writing_mode():
    while 1:
        var = raw_input()
        # some options with what to do with the var

def listening_mode():
    readbuffer = ""

    while 1:
        readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
        temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\r\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop()

        for line in temp:
            line = string.strip(line)
            prefix, command, rest, trailing = parse(line)

            # do something with the options u have

s=socket.socket()
try:
    s.connect((args.h, args.p))
except Exception, e:
    print("Something is wrong with %s:%d, Exception type is:\n%s" % (args.h, args.p, e))
    sys.exit()

s.send("NICK AAA\r\n")
s.send("USER AAA AAA AAA AAA\r\n")

thread.start_new_thread(writing_mode)
thread.start_new_thread(listenning_mode)
#main program waiting for signals
```

Comment: Have a look here, an example of socket and select usage: http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I still can't figure out, how this will handle my problem. I don't truly understand how the list of 3 sockets in select() will help me.

Comment: to catch SIGNIT, you may use `signal.signal` and add a condition on `while 1 and (something to do with signal.sigal...):`

Comment: but the problem is, that the program will be stucked on the reading function and never gets to while at time of the signal.

Comment: @Dracke, where is your reading function? I can't see it in your code.
you can create a signal handler and by time it stops the thread properly

Comment: var = raw_input() - thats one, readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024) this is the other

Comment: ok, so you basically put both server and client in the same place? they should be separate

Comment: nah, this is client that reads input from console (writing_mode) and than uses that to send information to server (for example /join #channel_name) and listens what the server tells him (if he is joined to the channel he wanted) in listenning_mode

Comment: have you tried just your `writing` or `reading` mode and see if they actually run? I see there are many missing parts

Comment: it works, the code is much longer, I had to shorten the functionality for the purpose of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this with non-blocking reading through select().

```
while condition:
    # s is socket to read from
    # for stdin use sys.stdin instead
    ready = select.select([s], [], [], 0)
    if ready[0]:
        #u can start read
```

The select function, goes on the reading function only if there is anything to read. Otherwise it goes to the while loop so the condition can stop it at any time.